# Communication between JS office add-in and VSTO add-in

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, vsto, office-addins

Hello and thanks in advance for the time you guys are spending reading this,

I need to understand if there's a way to make a COM/VSTO Office Add-in and a JS API Office add-in talk with each other. The reason why is, i like the UI part of JS and the extensibility to other systems, but i need functionalities that are only available on VSTO.. Like access to shape types, etc.

Is there a way to do this ? I've been searching for days and thinking. I came up with some sort of backend communication like SignalR or kafka but i didn't want to make something so complex just to do this. I'd rather go full VSTO if it comes to that..

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct mechanism for communication between two kind of Office add-ins. As a possible workaround you can use a back-end server to communicate between the two. Also you may consider setting up custom properties on items where you could track changes (for example, in Outlook).